# Django cache.clear() not working (LocMemCache, AWS)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### Background

I have a website running Django 2.0 on AWS ElasticBeanstalk. I have a couple views on my website that take some time to calculate, so I thought I'd look into some simple caching. I decided on LocMemCache because it looked like the quickest to set up that would meet my needs. (I'm using AWS, so using Memcached apparently requires ElastiCache, which adds cost and is additional setup overhead that I wanted to avoid.)

The views do not change often, and the site is not high-traffic, so I put long timeouts on the caches. There are three views where I have enabled caching:

1. A report generated inside a template – uses Template Fragment caching
2. A list of locations requested by AJAX and used in a JS library – uses per-view caching
3. A dynamically-generated binary file download – uses per-view caching

The caching is set up and works great.

The data that goes into these views is added and edited by other staff at my company, that are used to their changes appearing immediately. So in order to address questions such as, "I updated this data, why has the webpage not updated?" I wanted to create a "Clear Server Cache" button, accessible by staff, to force a cache reset.

The button is set up and functioning. It requests a view that calls `cache.clear()` from `django.core.cache`. I used the sledgehammer `cache.clear()` approach because the way to specify an individual per-view cache in code seems to be a bit clunky and convoluted, so the "clear it all" approach seemed adequate. And at the very least it should always "work" in the sense that all the data will get re-loaded again.

### The Problem

When I use the button to call `cache.clear()`, it only clears the Template Fragment cache. It does not seem to clear the per-view caches. Why?

According to [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#basic-usage),

> Be careful with this; `clear()` will remove *everything* from the cache, not just the keys set by your application.

So why is it not touching the per-view caches? Doesn't the warning seem to indicate that `clear()` is dangerous specifically *because* it's a sledgehammer and nothing at all is spared? What am I missing?

Does AWS use some kind of special memory that's immune to this sort of culling? (If this is the case, then why are the Template Fragments successfully cleared?) I did notice (and find it interesting) that the cache remains even after deploying a new image to the same environment.

I could switch to using Database caching, but I'd like to understand why this isn't working so I don't need to abandon LocMemCache as an option to ever use in the future.

I could also move the others to use Template Fragment caching, but if I ever expand the caching to fit other needs, I will want to be able to use per-view caching. Also, this solution would be less than ideal for a binary-file-download view.

#### `settings.py`

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
##        'LOCATION': '',
    },
}
```

#### `portfolio.html` (Cache #1 – Template Fragment)

```html
{% load static cache compress %}

...

<div id="total-portfolio-content">
{% cache 7200 portfolio %}{% include 'reports/total_portfolio/report_include.html' %}{% endcache %}
</div>
```

#### `map/urls.py` (Cache #2 – Per-view)

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url

app_name = 'map'
urlpatterns = [
    ## Yes, I know this uses the old-style url(). I have plans to upgrade the entire project.
    url(r'^(?P<tg>[\w-]+)/data.geojson$',
        cache_page(60 * 60 * 12)(
            views.NamedGeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=FacilityCoord)),
        name='tg-data'),
]
```

#### `resources/urls/__init__.py` (Cache #3 – Per-view)

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url

app_name = 'resources'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^download/$',
        cache_page(60 * 60 * 12)(
            views.DownloadMetricXLSX.as_view()),
        name='download'),
]
```

#### `myadmin/views.py` (Cache Clear button)

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

@staff_member_required(login_url=login_url)
def clear_cache(request):
    cache.clear()

    ## And because that doesn't seem to work as advertised, I also tried....
    ## taken from <https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1080/>
    try:
        cache._cache.clear()  # in-memory caching
        cache._expire_info.clear()
    except AttributeError:
        # I think this only applies to filesystem caching? Just grasping at straws.
        old_freq = cache._cull_frequency
        old_max = cache._max_entries
        cache._max_entries = 0
        cache._cull_frequency = 1
        cache._cull()
        cache._cull_frequency = old_freq
        cache._max_entries = old_max

    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

Comment: Any news on this one? I seem to have same issue, I am just getting started and trying to understand everything. I am running dev server and I set up throttling for my API that uses LocMemCache too. I am running cache.clear() in django shell but this doesn't restart the throttling cache until I rerun server. I know that more advanced setups are available but I am just trying to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I haven't seen any activity on this quesion, and never figured it out myself. I've been thinking to just abandon the LocMemCache concept and go for a database cache setup instead. I agree, it would be nice to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the response headers. The `cache_page` decorator automatically adds a `max-age` option to the `Cache-Control` header in the response. So the cache clear was working properly, clearing the local memory on the server, but the user's browser was instructed not to ask the server for updated data for the duration of the timeout. And my browser was happily complying (even after Ctrl-F5).

Fortunately, there are other decorators you can use to deal with this without much difficulty, now that it's clear what's happening. Django provides a number of [other decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers), such as `cache_control` or `never_cache`.

I ended up using `never_cache`, which turned the urls files into...

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache, cache_page

app_name = 'map'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<tg>[\w-]+)/data.geojson$',
        never_cache(cache_page(60 * 60 * 12)(
            views.NamedGeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=FacilityCoord))),
        name='tg-data'),
]
```

and

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache, cache_page

app_name = 'resources'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^download/$',
        never_cache(cache_page(60 * 60 * 12)(
            views.DownloadMetricXLSX.as_view())),
        name='download'),
]
```